# How to run Insert query in php script which table name is a number

Tags: php, sql, database

I need to insert values to my table 9998 using a php script. First I tested a query for check database connection (query that commented) it work fine. Now I need to run the second query but it won't

```
//$sql1  = "UPDATE testTable SET rule = 'TEST' WHERE gid =".$edge["gid"];
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO "9998"(forward_speed)VALUES (50);"
```

Note- I tested the insert query by executing in database using postgreSQL it executed  correctly.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using numbers as table names or if they start with a number, you need to escape them using backticks.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `9998` (forward_speed) VALUES (50);"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `9998` (forward_speed) VALUES (50);"
```